# Spring Batch with Spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

Getting the below error after adding `@EnableTask` in Spring Batch application

```
The bean 'transactionManager', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SimpleTaskConfiguration and overriding is disabled.
```

Comment: Which Spring Boot / Cloud Task versions are you using? Adding `--spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` should fix the issue.

Comment: That error should go away if you use the latest Spring Cloud Task milestones.  The RC for the 2.1 release is scheduled for this week (with the fixes in it).